# Change page depending on retrieved information from API - Ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, ionic-framework

I am retrieving records from an API for the current day. If `inventory_name = "Better luck next time!"`, I want it to push to the `FailResultsPage`. Else, I want it to push to the `ResultsPage`. My current codes is always directing me to the `ResultsPage` regardless of the results I get. What am I doing wrongly?

Provider

```
getUserSpin(spin_date: string){
return this.http.get<GamesRecords>(`${this.dataApiUrl}//someapi &filters[spin_date]=${spin_date}`,
  { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-TOKEN', this.getCookie('XSRF-TOKEN'))});}
```

.ts of the page

```
export class GamesPage {
  games: Games[];
  inventory_name: string = 'Better luck next time!';
  spin_date;
  date;
  gamed;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public datepipe: DatePipe, private alertCtrl: AlertController, private christmasProvider: ChristmasProvider, private storage: Storage) {

  gotoResultpage(){

      this.date = new Date();
      let spin_date = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      console.log(spin_date);
      this.christmasProvider.getUserSpin(spin_date).pipe(
        map((gamesResult: GamesRecords) => gamesResult && gamesResult.records)
      ).subscribe(gamed => {
        this.games = gamed;
        this.storage.set('inventory_name', gamed);
        console.log(this.gamed);
      });

      if(this.gamed = this.inventory_name){
        this.navCtrl.push(FailResultsPage);
        console.log('push to fail page');
        console.log(this.gamed);
      }

      else{
        this.navCtrl.push(ResultsPage);
        console.log('push to success page');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simple debugging like `console.log(this.gamed);` and `console.log(this.inventory_name);` to ensure the results you are comparing are the expected results before your `if()` condition is executed? I bet the `if()` condition isn't executing when you expect it to...

Comment: here if(this.gamed = this.inventory_name) use == instead of signle =

Comment: @NewToJS `this.gamed` returns me undefined

Comment: So if `this.gamed` returns undefined then your problem occurs before your `if()` condition "asynchronous" problem as I have stated in my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

As it is an asynchronous call, you can't know when it will be returned. So move if else statement into the subscribe function, try below code

> gotoResultpage(){
>
> ```
>   this.date = new Date();
>   let spin_date = this.datepipe.transform(this.date, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
>   console.log(spin_date);
>   this.christmasProvider.getUserSpin(spin_date).pipe(
>     map((gamesResult: GamesRecords) => gamesResult && gamesResult.records)
>   ).subscribe(gamed => {
>     this.games = gamed;
>     this.storage.set('inventory_name', gamed);
>     console.log(this.gamed);
>     if(this.gamed == this.inventory_name){
>       this.navCtrl.push(FailResultsPage);
>       console.log('push to fail page');
>       console.log(this.gamed);
>     }else{
>       this.navCtrl.push(ResultsPage);
>       console.log('push to success page');
>     }  
>   });
> ```
>
> }

Comment: I the above example what is the output of console.log(this.gamed) i think the problem is here -> this.games = gamed; this should be this.gamed = gamed;